# What are developers using for voice chat on Windows?

Tags: windows, voice, fmod

On Xbox360 XHV2 is used for dealing with voice data, and XAudio2 is used for the low-level processing of that data. What is the XHV2 equivalent under Windows, assuming FMOD is used for the low-level audio processing? Previously DirectPlay.Voice was used to facilitate this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any standard feature built into Windows for this that I know of. There are libraries that will do it for you like [RakVoice](http://www.raknet.net/raknet/manual/rakvoice.html) for example, although that's integrated with RakNet. I believe the Steam APIs also have it built in.

Unfortunately Fmod lists it's voice chat support as coming in a future version - see http://www.fmod.org/index.php/products/fmodexdetailed and click on "Enhanced Internet Features".

That means you'll probably have to do it manually:

1. Record audio from a microphone.
2. Optionally process the audio to improve voice clarity. [Compress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_range_compression#Voice) it for example.
3. Encode it using a low bandwidth and low latency codec like [SPEEX](http://www.speex.org/).
4. Send it across the network.
5. Decode it at the other end.
6. Play it back.

Fmod obviously has APIs for steps 1 and 6. It also has audio codec support so it should help a bit with step 3 and 5. The main thing you need to do is step 4.

Comment: Ohh, good call on RakNet. The code I'm looking at is using RakNet, but I didn't even realize that there was RakVoice.